# Dynamic XSL file

Tags: xslt, transform, xsl-fo, xslcompiledtransform

I have 3 XSL files which have paths in them to something like C:\templates\Test\file.pdf

This path isn't always going to be the same and rather than having it hard coded in the XSL, I'd like it so that the path C:\templates\test\ is replaced with a tag [BASEPATH] and when I read in the xsl file into the XSLTransform object (yes I know it's been deprecated, I may move over to the XSLCompiledTransform at the same time), I'd like the tag [BASEPATH] to be replaced with the absolute file path of the web folder (or Server.MapPath("~") seeing as it is in .net)

I thought I may be able to make an XSLLoader aspx page which takes the name of the XSL file through the querystring and then returns the XSL file via xml content-type. When I try this, I get a 503 error though so I'm not sure if you can pass urls like this into the XSLTransform.Load method.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: What's that to do with XSL-FO?

Comment: <fo:external-graphic src="url('C:\ApplicationSite\Test\Assets\Images\Logo.gif')"></fo:external-graphic>

That's part of the XSL - using it to make a PDF. Don't know if there is a way to use a relative path to specify an external graphic in XSL-FO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at XSL parameters?

```
<xsl:param name="basepath" select="'C:\Users\Graeme\'" />

<xsl:value-of select="document(concat($basepath, 'test.pdf'))" />
```

Then, most decent XSLT engines have a way to set a root level parameter from outside.

Comment: Thanks, that's the way I've gone - have got the variable being used now, just need to figure out how to set the root level param from the C#.

Comment: Great, that's it working now - thanks - to pass in arguments in C# to the deprecated XslTransform object, you do the following:

XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();
xslArg.AddParam("day","",day);
xslArg.AddParam("year","",year);
xslArg.AddParam("weather","",weather);

XslTransform xslt = new XslTransform();
xslt.Load(stylesheet);

XPathDocument xpathdocument = new XPathDocument(filename);

XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("priceClassExample.html",null);

xslt.Transform(xpathdocument, xslArg, writer);
writer.Close();