# Displaying xml nodes dynamically and applying style to specific nodes using recursion

Tags: xslt, xpath, xsl-fo

Below is my xml file.

```
<xml>
<top>
 <main>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>John</lastname>
    <table></table>
    <chapter>
       <firstname>Alex</firstname>
       <lastname>Robert</lastname>
       <p>Sample text chap</p>
       <figure name="f1.svg"></figure>
       <chapter>
          <firstname>Rebec</firstname>
          <lastname></lastname>
          <p>Sample text</p>
          <figure name="f2.svg"></figure>
       </chapter>
    </chapter>
 </main>
</top>
</xml>
```

**Desired output:**

```
<bold>John
table
<bold>Robert
Sample text chap
f1.svg
<bold> Rebec
Sample text
f2.svg
```

**Explaination:** I have written an xslt to do this. I need to fetch the xml nodes dynamically. I cannot write: xsl:apply-templates select='main/lastname'. Because my xml format could change anytime. 
I have tried a logic to first fetch all the xml nodes using '$root/*'. Then if 'table' element is encountered, i use xsl:apply-templates select='current()[name() = 'TABLE']' and perform table creation operations.
This works fine. I get the desired output but my figure elements only displays f1.svg at every place in the output. f2.svg is not shown.
And how do I match only 'lastname' and make it bold?
I want to make the code as generic/modular as possible so that it loops through all the elements of the xml tree and does some formatting on the specific nodes.
Below is a recursive xslt. With this my data is getting repeated. I am writing recursive template because xslt is not sequential.

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:call-template name="FetchNodes">
<xsl:with-param name="endIndex" select="$NumberOfNodes" />
<xsl:with-param name="startIndex" select="1" />
<xsl:with-param name="context" select="$root/*" />
</xsl:call-template>


<xsl:template name="FetchNodes">
    <xsl:param name="endIndex" />
    <xsl:param name="startIndex" />
    <xsl:param name="context" />
    <xsl:if test="$startIndex &lt;= $endIndex">
           <xsl:if test="$context[$startIndex][name() = 'table']"">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="$context[$startIndex][name() = 'table']"" mode="table" />
      </xsl:if>
            <xsl:call-template name="FetchNodes">
        <xsl:with-param name="endIndex" select="$endIndex" />
        <xsl:with-param name="startIndex" select="$startIndex + 1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="context" select="$context" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="table">   
       <xsl:value-of select="node()" />
    </xsl:template>
```

With the above xslt, something is incorrect in the xpath of apply templates. Output is not proper.
I want XSL FO output.

Can anybody suggest something?

Comment: Why did you delete your last question just to ask another one with the same content (which is slightly confusing)?

Comment: Hi Mathias. People were getting too confused with that one.

Comment: Removing the question and asking it again does nothing to reduce confusion. On the contrary. User had commented on your last question suggesting ways to improve it - which now are lost.

Comment: Are you outputting HTML, or XSL-FO? It would make it easier to provide an answer if you showed the actual output you expect (either HTML code, or XSL-FO code), rather than a plain textual representation. Also, you say you have written some XSLT, so it would help if you showed this XSLT in the question too, as you might find you are not too far off a solution already. Thank you!

Comment: I have shared the xslt. I want XSL FO output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic XSL file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707674/dynamic-xsl-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem it displaying "f1.svg" instead of "f2.svg" is because of this line

```
<xsl:variable name="ImageName">
    <xsl:value-of select="$root/*/chapter/figure/@name" />
</xsl:variable>
```

You are already positioned on a **figure** at this point, so you only need to use a relative xpath expression here. The one you are currently using is an absolute path and so will always return the first **@name** attribute regardless of your context. It should look this this

```
<xsl:variable name="ImageName">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Or better still, like this

```
<xsl:variable name="ImageName" select="@name" />
```

Having said, the code is in a template that is trying to match an element a **FIGURE** element, which does not exist in the XML you have shown us. You can actually simplify the template match to this, for example

```
 <xsl:template match="figure" mode="figure">
```

As for making things bold, you can just add the **font-weight** attribute to any block you want to make bold. Something like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="self::lastname">
      <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:value-of select="text()" /></fo:inline>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

**EDIT:** Having said all that, you may not be taking the correct approach to the problem. It may be better to use template matching, taking advantage of XSLT's built-in template to navigate over the document. Essentially, just write a template for each element you want to match, and generate the output, and then carry on matching its children.

For example, to turn a **chapter** into an **fo:block** do this

```
<xsl:template match="chapter">
   <fo:block>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

To output the **firstname** in bold, do this

```
<xsl:template match="firstname">
   <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
   </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

To turn a **figure** into an image, do this (Note the use of Attribute Value Templates here, the curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally)

```
<xsl:template match="figure">
   <fo:block>
      <fo:external-graphic src="../resources/{@name}" content-height="60%" scaling="uniform" padding-left="2cm"/>
   </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT as a starting point, and build on it

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="main">
      <fo:block>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </fo:block>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="chapter">
      <fo:block>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </fo:block>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="firstname">
      <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
         <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </fo:inline>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="lastname"/>

   <xsl:template match="figure">
      <fo:block>
         <fo:external-graphic src="../resources/{@name}" content-height="60%" scaling="uniform" padding-left="2cm"/>
      </fo:block>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I appreciate your solution. But for the figure I cannot put $name directly. Because by the time the control reaches this statement - <xsl:variable name="ImageName" select="@name" />, the current node is changed and there is no @name attribute available there to the current node. Thats why I was giving the absolute path. Now with your answer I cannot get the figure in my pdf. Can you please suggest on this?

Comment: Is the problem because the template the code is in is trying to match a node called 'FIGURE', but there no such nodes in the source XML (XSLT is case-sensitive)? It would help a lot if you showed a complete (but small) sample of XSLT, that could be used to reproduce the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have edited my xslt above in the question. Please check. The nodes : 'chapter', figure' and 'table' elements could be any where in the xml. I am trying make the code modular so that, whenever any such node is encountered, the appropriate template should be applied. i.e., a table should be created if table tag is encountered, text for 'chapter' tag and figure for 'figure' tag. The order of the output in the pdf should be same as the order of data present in the input xml. And also that the depth of these nodes could be any where in the tree.

Comment: I've made an edit to my question, to show an alternate approach to solving the problem.

Comment: Hi Tim, I am trying the recursive way to do this. Because XSLT is not sequential and this is causing alot of problems when the xml changes. The output is not as per the xml. It is based on the order of template call. I will put the recursive xslt in my question. I know I am asking for too much. But I badly need help.

Comment: In the recursice xslt, the output is coming four times though there is only one 'table' tag in the xml. because under 'main' tag, there are 4 sub tags.

Comment: I am not really sure what you want to achieve, I am afraid. Ideally the question needs to show a small, but representative, sample of your XML, and the XSL-FO you expect to be generated from that XML. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Tim. But I have found the solution with a recursive template call. It works now. Thank you for your help:)